# Load component based on logged in status of user without changing url

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular. In my `AppComponent`, I would like to display a login page if the user is not logged.

I have an Authentication service

```
export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor() {}

    logout() {
        // logs out user
    }

    login(user) {
        //logs in user           

    }

    checkCredentials() {
        //checks if logged in 
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
// import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({

})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

}
```

login.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

What can I do in app.component for the main page to load the `LoginComponent` if user isn't logged in or `DashboardComponent` if user is logged in without routing to different urls?

Comment: Have you tried skipLocationChange?  this.router.navigate(['/url'], { skipLocationChange: true });?https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras 

Or you need to avoid routing completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your token into localstorage and based on expiry date of that token you can check the validity of token and based on that you can redirect to Loginpage OR Dashboard page, 
You can check validity logic in Guards.

If you want full example please refer this link:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

and there auth.guard.ts is doing exactly what you need